# Handling JSON single object and array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to work with some JSON data that is being returned to me. Depending on what I request I can either get back something that looks like:

```
{
"TotalRecords":2,
"Result":
    [
        {
        "Id":24379,
        "AccountName":"foo"
        },
        {
        "Id":37209,
        "AccountName":"bar"
        }
    ],
"ResponseCode":0,
"Status":"OK",
"Error":"None"
}
```

or

```
{
    "Result":
    {
        "Id":24379,
        "AccountName":"foo"
    },
    "ResponseCode":0,
    "Status":"OK",
    "Error":"None"
}
```

So sometimes "Result" is an array of Results or "Result" could be a single response.

I've tried using the answer from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n) but I still get errors.

In particular I'm getting a

```
Newtonsoft.json.jsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'...
```

Custom converter looks like:

```
public class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objecType)
        {
            return (objecType == typeof(List<T>));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objecType, object existingValue,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
            }
            return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

My response class(es) look like

```
public class TestResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("Result")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<string>))]
        public List<DeserializedResult> Result { get; set; }
    }
public class DeserializedResult
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally my request looks like

```
List<TestResponse> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestResponse>>(response.Content);
```

Comment: do you have only two types of answers?

Comment: They'll only ever follow one of those two formats, though the content will obviously be different. Sometimes "Result" will have several fields, other times only one or two regardless of if it returns a single object or an array of up to 100 objects.

Comment: Now I'll try to write a code-solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is fine, it just needs a few type tweaks.

This line

```
List<TestResponse> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestResponse>>(response.Content);
```

needs to be like this, because your response is an `object`, not a `List`.

```
TestResponse list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestResponse>(response);
```

Then your custom deserializer attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<string>))]
```

needs to become:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<DeserializedResult>))]
```

because your `Result` object is not a `string` or an array of `string`s, it's either an array of `DeserializedResult`s or a `DeserializedResult`.

Comment: I owe you a beer (or whatever you drink). I'm kicking myself that it was such as minor tweak to get it working. A thousand thanks!

Comment: It just saved my day :)

Comment: Thanks. This was of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that there is no way to understend which type of response do you have due desirialization. Thats why i propose to check manualy type of response:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public class Result
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string AccountName { get; set; }
        }

        public class ModelWithArray
        {
            public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
            public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
            public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Error { get; set; }
        }

        public class Result2
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string AccountName { get; set; }
        }

        public class ModelWithoutArray
        {
            public Result2 Result { get; set; }
            public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Error { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main(params string[] args)
        {
            //string json = "{\"TotalRecords\":2,\"Result\":[{\"Id\":24379,\"AccountName\":\"foo\"},{\"Id\":37209,\"AccountName\":\"bar\"}], \"ResponseCode\":0,\"Status\":\"OK\",\"Error\":\"None\"}";
            string json = "{\"Result\":{\"Id\":24379,\"AccountName\":\"foo\"},\"ResponseCode\":0,\"Status\":\"OK\",\"Error\":\"None\"}";

            if (checkIsArray(json))
            {
                ModelWithArray data = JsonConver.DeserializeObject<ModelWithArray >(json);
            }else
            {
                ModelWithoutArray data = JsonConver.DeserializeObject<ModelWithoutArray>(json);
            }

        }

        static bool checkIsArray(string json)
        {

            Dictionary<string, object> desData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

            if (desData["Result"].GetType().Name.Contains("Array"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `i propose to check manualy type of response`. you don't have to, the package `newtonsoft.json` provides ways of avoiding this.