# JSON Deserialise handles Array but doesn't like a single "object"

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm handling XML data coming in, the "top" of the data is fixed, the "rows" within may vary in content and quantity.

My code works when deserializing to JSON then to a data table, but if the number of rows is 1, it fails.
I get this error message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'DynamicJSON.DynamicJSON+Row[]' because the type requires a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

I'm probably missing something really obvious, but haven't been able to find an answer yet.

I've tried the solution in this post but end up with a stack overflow error (somewhat ironic...)
[Handling JSON single object and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100383/handling-json-single-object-and-array)

**My code for handling the original xml:**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText("C:\\temp\\file.xml").ToString());
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
                DynamicJSON.Rootobject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DynamicJSON.Rootobject>(json);

                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
                JArray jArray = (JArray)jObject["SOAP-ENV:Envelope"]["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["reportresponse"]["row"];

                DataTable jdt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jArray.ToString(), (typeof(DataTable)));
```

**My Class**

```
class DynamicJSON
{
        public class Rootobject
        {
            [JsonProperty("SOAP-ENV:Envelope")]
            public SOAPENVEnvelope SOAPENVEnvelope { get; set; }
        }

        public class SOAPENVEnvelope
        {
            public string xmlnsSOAPENV { get; set; }
            public string xmlnsSOAPENC { get; set; }
            public string xmlnsxsi { get; set; }
            public string xmlnsxsd { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("SOAP-ENV:Header")]
            public SOAPENVHeader SOAPENVHeader { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("SOAP-ENV:Body")]
            public SOAPENVBody SOAPENVBody { get; set; }
        }

        public class SOAPENVHeader
        {
            public string reportname { get; set; }
            public string reportstartdate { get; set; }
            public string reportenddate { get; set; }
            public string reportmerchantid { get; set; }
        }

        public class SOAPENVBody
        {
            public Reportresponse reportresponse { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("SOAP-ENV:Fault")]
            public SOAPENVFault? SOAPENVFault { get; set; }
        }

        public class SOAPENVFault
        {
            public string faultcode { get; set; }
            public string faultstring { get; set; }
        }


        [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<Row>))]
        public class Reportresponse
        {
            public Row[] row { get; set; }
        }

        public class Row
        {
            [JsonExtensionData]
            public Dictionary<string, JToken> child { get; set; }

            public Row()
            {
                child = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
            }
        }
}
```

**My XML looks like this:**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <reportname>ReportName</reportname>
        <reportstartdate>2020-Jun-1</reportstartdate>
        <reportenddate>2020-Jun-1</reportenddate>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <reportresponse>
            <row>
                <rowid>1</rowid>
                <value1>1</value1>
                <value2>1</value2>
                <value3>1</value3>
            </row>
        </reportresponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**The JSON is converted to this (as a single "row")**

```
{
  "SOAP-ENV:Envelope": {
    "@xmlns:SOAP-ENV": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "@xmlns:SOAP-ENC": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "@xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "SOAP-ENV:Header": {
      "reportname": "ReportName",
      "reportstartdate": "2020-Jun-1",
      "reportenddate": "2020-Jun-1"
    },
    "SOAP-ENV:Body": {
      "reportresponse": {
        "row": {
          "rowid": "1",
          "value1": "1",
          "value2": "1",
          "value3": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON array:**

```
{
  "SOAP-ENV:Envelope": {
    "@xmlns:SOAP-ENV": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "@xmlns:SOAP-ENC": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "@xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "SOAP-ENV:Header": {
      "reportname": "ReportName",
      "reportstartdate": "2020-Jun-1",
      "reportenddate": "2020-Jun-1"
    },
    "SOAP-ENV:Body": {
      "reportresponse": {
        "row": [
          {
            "rowid": "1",
            "value1": "1",
            "value2": "1",
            "value3": "1"
          },
          {
            "rowid": "2",
            "value1": "2",
            "value2": "2",
            "value3": "2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried without the SingleOrArrayConverter, I've also tried using dynamic and string instead of `SingleOrArrayConverter<Row>` as well but so far no luck.

Appreciate anyone (politely) telling me where I'm missing the obvious..

Comment: How does your JSON look like?

Comment: Apologies, I've included the 2 JSON examples to help